# Add pseudo element ::before & ::after to html tag

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm new to using pseudo elements, and there is something i'm trying to achieve and it's not working, and also can't find it anywhere on internet.

I want to add ::before and ::after to a `<header>` tag. But how?
Is it even possible? or am i getting the idea of the pseudo elements completely wrong?

[image]

Comment: I think you want to add "css" as a tag to your question

Comment: One of the icons in the Stackoverflow editor is labeled Code Snippet. Click it and show us a test case that demonstrates the problem. As @sircapsalot's answer shows, what you want it possible, but we can't tell why your code isn't work without seeing your code.

Comment: After digging in some more, i figured out that i had my header::before, header::after inside my header tag in the css. i feel stupid xD Thanks guys :) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably aren't setting any content.

```css
header::before, header::after {
  content: "";
  ...
}
```

```html
<header>
  My header
</header>
```

When I add that in, i get this:

[image]

Comment: what i mean is, when i inspect my header element, it doesn't have a ::before / ::after element.

Comment: i put a picture in there.  click "run code snippet" and inspect the header

Comment: when i add the content: ""; it still doesn't add them. (i edited my post, see image)

Comment: @yinshiro it doesn't show because it is generated by CSS and still doesn't exist in the document itself. The dom inspector will never show it to you cause it is not part of the DOM.

Comment: @GCyrillus — It does show as the screenshot in this answer already demonstrates.

Comment: @Quentin at screen yes , thats the job of CSS actually. Can you reach via javascript ? nop because it doesn't exist. can you select it and copy/paste it ? nop, cause it doesn't exist in the DOM :) This is my point

Comment: @GCyrillus it does show, because other elements do get the ::before ::after (see my screenshot first post)

Comment: @GCyrillus — That point doesn't seem very relevant, and your statement (that they wouldn't show in the DOM inspector) is flat out wrong.

Comment: never mind, maybe i missunderstood the question  DOM it :)